# SQL query using MAX with multiple table joins

Tags: sap, advantage

I have a working SQL script to show results that join multiple tables.  However, I want to limit the results of the join to show only one record per a given "Chart Number" value in one of the tables.  Here is the original query:

```
SELECT  
MWPAT."Chart Number",
MWPAT."First Name", 
MWCAS."Case Number",
MWCAS."Marital Status"

FROM  
MWPAT MWPAT  INNER JOIN MWCAS MWCAS ON 
      (MWCAS."Chart Number" = MWPAT."Chart Number")
       INNER JOIN MWINS MWINS ON 
      (MWINS.Code = MWCAS."Insurance Carrier #1")
       INNER JOIN MWTRN MWTRN ON 
      (MWTRN."Chart Number" = MWPAT."Chart Number")
      
Where MWTRN."Date From"> '01/01/2000'
    
GROUP BY  
MWPAT."Chart Number",
MWPAT."First Name", 
MWCAS."Case Number",
MWCAS."Marital Status"

ORDER BY  MWPAT."Chart Number"
```

And here is the sample output for this query:

| Chart Number | First Name | Case Number | Marital Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | John | 2 | Single |
| 000001 | John | 8 | Single |
| 000001 | John | 15 |  |
| 000005 | Sarah | 35 | Single |
| 000005 | Sarah | 42 | Married |
| 000009 | Fred | 7 | Single |
| 000036 | Mary | 89 | Divorced |

I need to limit this output to only show one line per "Chart Number" column of the MWCAS table, based on the highest "Case Number" value that appears for the given Chart Number.  For example- the output would show this instead:

| Chart Number | First Name | Case Number | Marital Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | John | 15 |  |
| 000005 | Sarah | 42 | Married |
| 000009 | Fred | 7 | Single |
| 000036 | Mary | 89 | Divorced |

Note that each Chart Number only shows one line now, which is based on the information of the MWCAS table, and choosing the highest Case Number value for the output.

I have tried different uses of MAX but I cannot find a syntax that works.  I'm querying Advantage Database, so this could be limiting. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  MWPAT."Chart Number", 
  MWPAT."First Name", 
  (SELECT MAX(MWCAS2."Case Number")
   FROM MWCAS MWCAS2
   WHERE MWCAS2."Chart Number" = MWPAT."Chart Number") AS "Case Number", 
  MWCAS."Marital Status"
FROM MWPAT MWPAT  
LEFT OUTER JOIN MWCAS MWCAS ON 
      (MWCAS."Chart Number" = MWPAT."Chart Number")
LEFT OUTER JOIN MWINS MWINS ON 
     (MWINS.Code = MWCAS."Insurance Carrier #1")
LEFT OUTER JOIN MWTRN MWTRN ON 
     (MWTRN."Chart Number" = MWPAT."Chart Number")
      
Where MWTRN."Date From"> '01/01/2000'
ORDER BY  MWPAT."Chart Number"
```

Without a DBFiddle to verify, I may have made a typo.

Note

1. The left outer join gets only the rows from the second table that match the first
2. The sub-select gets the maximum value for the Case Number.
3. Since MWCAS is used twice, I have used a different alias for it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Rohit,

The query runs but I'm still getting duplicate rows for each Chart Number.  I can see the MAX command is used, but it's only replacing the Case Number with the MAX value.  (So the same MAX Case Number appears for each duplicate line.

I need the output to only print a single record per Chart Number- where the MWCAS fields will only print the values of the MAX (or highest) Case Number only (no duplicate lines, and the other Case number values are ignored, for each Chart Number.)

Any other suggestions on this format?
Thank you again

Comment: As I said, without it being on a dbfiddle it is hard to give the correct query.    If it's returning duplicates, then you have neglected to mention that MWPAT can have the same user twice. Please edit your question and post table schemas and sample data in each table (to match the results in your question)